# Book with a princess and a bodyguard, who I think was named Dog

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember the princess had to perform some sort of ceremony where she shoved a sword through the chest of three different men, so that they would be bound to her to protect her. At the end of the story she does some sort of spell that makes her travel back in time to the beginning of the story where she ends up going with the man her father wanted her to marry and they sail away on a boat?

I know it was part of a series but I never read the other books. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: When you were younger was when?  Five years ago?  Ten?  Twenty?  Fifty?  Was the book new then?  Or had it been around for a while?  You may want to see if [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9336/30870) makes you think of more details.

Comment: Possibly the Runelords series?

Comment: Possibly one of Dave Duncan's stories of the King's Blades?